How can I implement a hook with an arbitrary number of arguments using pluggy in python
I want to implement plugins using pluggy using one hook that can take an arbitrary number of arguments But whenever I want to call the hook it seems like the *arg argument is interpreted as a single positional argument.
Any Idea how to fix this?
Here is the code I use to replicate the problem:
import pluggy

# Defines the Specs of the hook
hookspec = pluggy.HookspecMarker("Example")


class Spec:
    @hookspec
    def method(self, *arg):
        """The method hook
        """
        pass


hookimpl = pluggy.HookimplMarker("Example")

# Defines the implementation of the hook


class Plugin:
    @hookimpl(specname="method")
    def method(self, *arg):
        print("Plugin method called with", arg)


# Defines the Plugin Manager
class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pm = pluggy.PluginManager("Example")
        self.pm.add_hookspecs(Spec)
        self.pm.register(Plugin())

    # Calls the hook
    def run(self, *arg):
        # Where it crashes
        self.pm.hook.method(*arg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.run(1, 2)


It defines only one plugin Plugin and one hook method.
Here is the error I get:
File "my_file.py", line 36, in run
    self.pm.hook.method(*arg)
TypeError: HookCaller.__call__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given


maybe it doesn't run your method but something else. maybe you should check print(  self.pm.hook.method ) or print( type( self.pm.hook.method ) ), etc.

I get <HookCaller 'method'> and <class 'pluggy._hooks.HookCaller'> respectively. It sounds right to me, especially since when I try to use one named argument it runs method without trouble.

if it gets only one argument then send all information as single list or single dirctionary.

I don't know why I didn't think of that, I can make it work thanks. But it's not very satisfying not knowing what was wrong.

maybe you would have to check source code to see how it works. Maybe @hookspec and/or @hookimpl (which may modify your method) expects only one value and you can't change it. Or it would need to modify @hookspec and/or hookimpl

For future Googlers:
As suggested by @furas I've updated my hook to only take one dictionary as an argument.
It seems that I can't use positional arguments when calling method through a hook.
So self.pm.hook(arg) and self.pm.hook(*arg) won't work but self.pm.hook(arg=arg) works fine (after updating the hook specs).
It's not the best solution but I see no workaround.
